# Generation of UUID1 is too slow

Tags: ubuntu, uuid

I upgraded my Ubuntu box from 13.04 to 14.04 LTS few days ago. Now I'm using libuuid-2.20.1. Anyway, after the upgrading, my UUID1 became very slow.

```
$ time uuidgen -t
f22c36aa-f511-11e3-9437-080027e59ea0
uuidgen -t  0.71s user 0.67s system 99% cpu 1.387 total

$ time uuidgen -t
fea4537c-f511-11e3-a6d5-080027e59ea0
uuidgen -t  0.72s user 0.67s system 99% cpu 1.394 total
```

0.7 seconds elapsed in `uuidgen -t`. What can make it slow?

-- updated --

Here's my `w` result:

```
$ w
 09:48:55 up 5 days, 22:56,  3 users,  load average: 0.37, 0.43, 0.43
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
sub      :0       :0               Wed10   ?xdm?   2days 22.69s init --user --state-fd 41 --re
sub      pts/26   sub.local        Wed18   16:47  17.00s 10.07s vim -b -b test/test_item.py
sub      pts/27   sub.local        Wed18    7.00s  8.63s  0.02s w
```

Comment: You might add the output of the `w` command, what's your system load like?  Is this consistent?  What else is running?  Those times are ... oh... abysmal! (7-350x slower than my machines!)

Comment: @lornix, I added my `w` result. Yes, this is consistent in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

It likely pulls randomness from **/dev/random**, (it does, I looked) which **WILL** block until enough entropy is accumulated to provide randomness.  Entropy is gained from keyboard usage, mouse, usb, hard drive activity, y'know... *random* things.

/dev/urandom does not block, but can't provide the level of randomness provided by /dev/random.  I know, sounds weird, evidently someone requires extremely random randomness, whereas I've always been satisfied with just plain random randomness.

uuidgen uses **/dev/random** for the -r (random) uuid's, and the system clock (and ethernet MAC) for the -t (time) uuid's.   If the clock used isn't granular enough, uuidgen may block until a certain minimum time has passed to ensure uniqueness.  (educated speculation on my part, no facts, apologies).

I'm using the same libuuid1 library, v2.20-1 on my system, and running a continuous loop shows my system generating random uuids (-r mode) at 0.002s (2ms) each, and time-based uuid's at 0.004s (4ms) each, average.  Is your system doing many (**many!**) other things currently? (Those times on a lightly loaded 2GHz machine.)

Also tested on my two Raspberry Pi's, they're averaging about 10ms (0.010s) for both time or random based uuid's... sounds like your system is pretty busy.  (Or you're running linux on an Atari 2600...)

Comment: To determine if `/dev/random` is blocking you can monitor `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` which gives the number of random bits in the pool. If that approaches to 0 /dev/random will block.

Comment: That “/dev/urandom (…) can't provide the level of randomness provided by /dev/random” is largely a myth. This is only true on a freshly installed system: once enough entropy has been accumulated, it doesn't go away. [`/dev/urandom` is suitable for high-security uses including key generation](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/3939). `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` actually have the same speed, the difference is that `/dev/random` might block waiting for more entropy. A system where `/dev/random` is slow is actually a system that isn't busy enough to generate entropy.

Comment: `uuidgen -r` is fast. Only `uuidgen -t` is very slow. So I don't think this concerns to `/dev/random`.

Comment: I started `uuidd` then `uuidgen -t` became fast. How can this fix the problem?